# Parse a string using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to parse a string but I am having a hard time. Here is an example piece of data. I need to get the part highlighted in bold so I can lookup the name up in our database.

[AZ - Domestic] **Acme Technologies LLC** - (8484383)"

So far, here is what I have tried:

```
$string = '[AZ - Domestic] Acme Technologies LLC - (8484383)"';
$start = stripos($string, ']');
$end = strripos($string , '-');

echo substr($string + 2, $start, $end);
```

But this is giving me this result: **Acme Technologies LLC - (8484383)"** But what I really need is this **Acme Technologies LLC**. I have tried all the PHP functions I know of to get this result but cannot seem to do so.

Comment: Can you provide more sample inputs/outputs?

Comment: i suck at regular expressions but here is a start: https://regex101.com/r/sznjl0/1

Comment: @esqew I have also tried `echo substr($string + 2, $start, $end);` and that gets rid of the **] ** at the beginning. I just cannot seem how to get rid of ** - (8484383)**

Comment: The last parameter of `substr` is supposed to be the length, not the end character position. -- Also yes, use a regex. strpos/substr are for those who don't know any better.

Comment: The second number is length, not position.

Answer (score 3):

The second argument of  `substr` is not the end-position of the substring, but the *length* of it. So do:

```
substr($string, $start + 2, $end - $start - 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the string will always be in that format, do this:

```
$regex   = '%\[.*\]\s(.*)\s-\s\(.*\)\"%';
$match   = preg_match($regex, $string);
$company = $match[1];
```

`$company` will contain your company name.

Regular Expressions are "de rigeur" for solving this sort of issue in this context.  I recommend downloading something like [Dr. Edmund Weitz` "The Regex Coach"](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) to help you in regex construction.

Answer (score 1):

Here are three different ways to use regex with a single function call:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/U0if5))

```
$string='[AZ - Domestic] Acme Technologies LLC - (8484383)"';
var_export(preg_match('~] \K(?: ?\w+)+~',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');  // target substring after known start symbols and before known end symbol
echo "\n";
var_export(preg_replace('~\[[^\]]+] | -.*~','',$string));  // remove bracketed and parentheticals
echo "\n";
var_export(preg_match('~(?:(?:\[[^\]]*]|\([^)]*\))(*SKIP)(*FAIL))|\w+(?: \w+)*~',$string,$out)?$out[0]:'fail');  // disqualify bracketed and parentheticals
```

Output:

```
'Acme Technologies LLC'
'Acme Technologies LLC'
'Acme Technologies LLC'
```

---

Since I am getting downvoted for absolutely no reason, I'll add some non-regex methods that will also prove successful on the input string:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VHQfk))

Two function calls:

```
$string = '[AZ - Domestic] Acme Technologies LLC - (8484383)"';
var_export(strstr(explode('] ',$string,2)[1],' -',true));
```

Three function calls:

```
$string = '[AZ - Domestic] Acme Technologies LLC - (8484383)"';
$start=strpos($string,']')+2;  // bump offset +2 to eliminate `] `
$length=strpos($string,' - (')-$start;  // substract ending offset from starting offset to find length
echo "\n\n$start & $length\n";
var_export(substr($string,$start,$length));
```

*Notice that there is no need to use case-insensitivity on `strpos()` when searching for non-alphabetical characters.  I also avoid match from the end of the string `r` by setting the needle to `- (`.  By extending the needle toward the front of the string, I avoid having to perform an extra subtraction to calculate `$length`.

Output:

```
'Acme Technologies LLC'

16 & 21
'Acme Technologies LLC'
```

p.s. I use `var_export()` on these string values to express the fact that there are no leading or trailing spaces to trim from my output.